# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

On my website I am trying to return a list which shows the users that the current user is following but I keep on recieving the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'`

Any help would be greatful

**User Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            return View(new Followuser()
                       {
                           User1ID = db.Followusers.Where(u => u.User1ID == currentUser.Id).ToList()
                       });

        }
```

**Followuser model**

```
public class Followuser
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string User1ID { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string User2ID { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Well yes - the `User1ID` property is a `string` property. You're trying to assign a `List<T>` to it (for some `T` we don't know about, possibly `Followuser` itself). Why are you doing that, and how did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `ToList` for no obvious reason. It would also make things clearer if you moved the query out of the return statement. Breaking your code down, you've effectively got:

```
// We're not certain what type `db.Followusers` is, to be honest.
List<Foo> list = db.Followusers.Where(u => u.User1ID == currentUser.Id)
                               .ToList();
Followuser user = new Followuser() { User1ID = list };
return View(user);
```

Do you see how that middle statement doesn't make sense?

I *suspect* you just want the following, assuming that `db.Followusers` is really something like `IQueryable<Followuser>`:

```
// Single checks that there's exactly one record matching the predicate.
Followuser user = db.Followusers.Single(u => u.User1ID == currentUser.Id);
return View(user);
```

Or given that it's now fairly short and simple:

```
return View(db.Followusers.Single(u => u.User1ID == currentUser.Id));
```